# How to add a external link to a item within a list in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a list in vue that displays a bunch of filtered messages like this:

```
<v-card>
   <v-list-item-group
        v-model="model">
           <v-list-item
            v-for="msg in selectedMessages"
            :key="msg"
            :value="msg">
                <v-btn
                icon
                disabled
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-list-item-content>
                   <v-list-item-title>
                   <strong>{{msg.Subject}} </strong>
                   </v-list-item-title>
                   <v-list-item-subtitle>
                   {{msg.MsgFrom}}
                   </v-list-item-subtitle>
                </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
   </v-list-item-group>
</v-card>
```

Here I am displaying each msg within a group of filtered messages (`selectedMessages`). I also added a button next to every msg within the list so that I can click on that button and the associated message's `MessagePath` will load on another page. `MessagePath` is just a url to a website that I want. Each message has a different `MessagePath`. With each message there is this kind of data:

```
  "mailbox": "example",
  "MsgFrom": "example@gmail.com",
  "MsgTo": "sample@outlook.com,
  "Subject": "subject_one"
  "MessagePath": "www.google.com"
```

I want to be able to click on the button next to the individual message that is in the list and have it load the `MessagePath` for that specific email. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add anchor tag instead button `<a :href="msg.MessagePath" target="_blank">{{msg.MessagePath}}</a>`